# How to get inline equation in pdf document using rmarkdown?

Tags: r, pdf, latex, r-markdown

I have some trouble trying to get an inline equation in my pdf document when rendering my rmarkdownd document.

I use the inline equation of the rstudio example: http://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/rmarkdown-reference.pdf

this my example code:

```
---
title: "Test"
author: "test test"
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
    number_sections: yes
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: 3
  html_document:
    css: tables.css
    number_sections: yes
    theme: cerulean
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: 3
subtitle: test test test
mainfont: Calibri Light
fontsize: 12pt
header-includes:
- \usepackage[dutch]{babel}
- \usepackage{fancyhdr}
- \pagestyle{fancy}
- \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{this is a fancy foot}
- \usepackage{dcolumn}
- \usepackage{here}
- \usepackage{longtable}
- \usepackage{caption}
- \captionsetup{skip=2pt,labelsep=space,justification=justified,singlelinecheck=off}
---

$$ 
  A = \pi*r^{2} 
$$
```

I also tried `$A = \pi*r^{2}$`.
I keep on getting this `Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 43` error when trying to knit it as a pdf. What am I doing wrong?

*Edit*

I use R v3.2.1, Rstudio Version 0.99.465 and knitr version 1.11

*Edit2*

a 'simple' code like `$e\"$` gives no error.

*Edit3*

This code gives no error, and renders a nice looking fraction:

```
$$
  \frac{a}{b}
$$
```

However, it does give an error when I change the code a bit:

```
$$
  \frac{1}{2}
$$
```

*Edit4*

I updated RStudio to Version 0.99.489, and R to v3.2.2. There was no success.

*Edit5*

When rendering an html document instead of a pdf the output is as expected. So the latex code is the right one.

(and now it officially drives me mad...)

My final conclusion is that the latex code doesn't take numbers or the '=' sign when rendering pdf. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: The example you posted runs without an error on my Mac with OSX Yosemite, R 3.2.2 and knitr 1.11.

Comment: Thanks for checking. I have a windows machine. I will add some extra information soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally succeeded in solving the problem.

```
$$
  A = \pi*r^{2}
$$
```

has to be turned into

```
$$
 A\text{=}\pi*r^{\text{2}}
$$
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly related:

- (double) $$ creates a standalone formula block;
- (single) $ inlines a formula block along text.